# code is just freezing and not outputting anything

Tags: c++

so i have an input.txt file that contains english-german words
for example book-buch, area-Bereich etc (those "-" are also included)
i have to code a small translator so if input book the code has to output buch and vise versa
i already coded the english to german output but for some reason when i try the same logic on german to english it doesnt output anything

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;



int main() {
    ifstream ifs("input.txt");
    ofstream ofs("history.txt", ifstream::app);
    int a, b, c = 0, j;
    string m, l, p[100];
    for (a = 0; a < 50; a++) {
        ifs >> p[a];
        m = p[a];
    }
    cin >> l;
    for (a = 0; a < 50; a++) {
        if (l == p[a].substr(l.size() + 1, p[a].size())) {  //here's the problem
            cout << p[a].substr(0, p[a].size() - l.size() + 1);

        }
        if (l == p[a].substr(0, l.size())) { //english to german
            cout << p[a].substr(l.size() + 1, p[a].size());
            ofs << l << "-" << p[a].substr(l.size() + 1, p[a].size());
            ofs << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: lol im starting to think that the solution is very obvious argh

Comment: having tried using gdb? When new to code gdb is always the best friend of yours

Comment: When you've made the mistake before, yes. Otherwise you need to  do a bit of reading [on `substr`, what it expects and how it works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). For example, in `p[a].substr(l.size() + 1, p[a].size())`, what if `l` is bigger than `p[a]`? Should get an exception. But what if the second parameter is too large?

Answer (score 0):

i used a different method

```
for (a = 0; a < 50; a++) {
        pos = p[a].find("-");
        if (l == p[a].substr(pos + 1)) {
            pos = p[a].find("-");
            cout << p[a].substr(0, pos);
```

also somehow forgot that c++ compiler was case sensitive
silly me